# Android does define a string value for different screen orientation

Tags: android

I have a `RecyclerView` in my layout.And I use `GridLayoutManager` for it.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                app:spanCount="3" />
```

Now I want to show different item count on one line.Such as if user screen orientation is port the `spanCount` is 3 or is 6.

I don't want define two layout file,Could I define two values file for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create different values folders like

'values' & 'values-land'

then create integers resource files(integers.xml) in both the above folders with resources like this

in values

`<resources><integer name="grid_columns">3</integer></resources>`

in values-land

```
<resources><integer name="grid_columns">5</integer></resources>
```

then in your gridlayout manager call integer value like this

```
    ////setting grid size from values/integers (pre defined for each size)
    int spanCount = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.grid_columns);

    ////get layout manager for recyclerView in grid layout manager span count 2 means 2 columns
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), spanCount);
```

this way for landscape it will select 'values-land' and for portrait it will choose 'values'